# Remove ar1[][] from ar2[][][]

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove a 2d arraylist from another 3d arraylist.
I mean, delete all the ar1[][] from ar2[][][]
I can't understand why my code is not deleting all of them:

```
    public void removeSame(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ar1,ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> ar3)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<ar3.size();k++)
            for(int j=0;j<ar3.size();j++)
                if(isSame(ar1,ar3.get(k)))
                {
                    ar3.remove(k);
                }
    }
    public boolean isSame(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ar1,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ar2)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<ar2.size();k++)
            for(int j=0;j<ar2.size();j++)
                if(!ar1.get(k).get(j).equals(ar2.get(k).get(j)))
                    return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: explain what your code is doing, instead of what you want it to do.

Comment: Searching for ar1 in ar3 and if it finds it, it removes it from ar3. btw I'm speaking about values not references.

Comment: Why do you have the second loop (the one with j) in removeSame?

Comment: why do you need second `for` in `removeSame` method?

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed.. too many hours infornt the screen. let me check if it fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see one issue when there are more than one occurrences of `ar1` in `ar3`. After first removal of `ar1` from `ar3` using `ar3.remove(k);`, the index and size of `ar3` ArrayList is changed ie. both size and indexes are reduced by one. Now when you continue your loop, it will skip one element in between as you continue using the original index. Also your inner `for` loop seems to be unnecessary.

There are two ways to resolve the issue.

Option1: User List#iterator i.e.

```
Iterator<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> iter = ar3.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(isSame(ar1, iter.next())){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Option2: After removal, reduce the index i.e. `k` value by one before continuing e.g.

```
    for(int k=0;k<ar3.size();k++){
       if(isSame(ar1,ar3.get(k))){
                ar3.remove(k--);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an array, your 3d array shrinks. The next iteration skips an element. For example, if your array has 10 elements and you remove #5, the next iteration goes to what used to be #7 but now is #6. #6 is now in #5, and you skip it. Decrement k when you remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is this

```
while(ar3.remove(ar1)){};
```